# How to identify records that belong to each group, while summerising to get the counts in R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, dplyr, plyr

I want to perform a groupby of 2 given columns, count how many rows in those groups and also to store which rows(ids) belong to each group.

The following helps me to groupby and get the counts

```
set.seed(1000)
df <- data.frame(col1= sample(c(1:15), 15, replace = F),
col2=sample(c("aa", "bb","cc"), 15, replace=TRUE),
col3=sample(c('a','b','c','d'), 15, replace=TRUE,    prob=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.20, 0.30)))

View(df)
```

[image]

```
grp<- df%>%
group_by(col2, col3) %>%
summarise(n=n())
```

[image]

If col1 stores row ids, what's the proper way to keep track of all the rowids belonging to each group?

Comment: Do you want a separate list of the row ids by groups? I ask because, if `df[,1]` stores row ids already, and `df[,3]` and `df[,2]` are unambiguous, dont you already have this information stored within the structure of your `df`?

Comment: yes, thats the requirement: to have separate lists of the row ids by groups

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Roman, please check if its okay now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you are after now. Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1000)
df <- data.frame(col1= sample(c(1:15), 15, replace = F),
                 col2=sample(c("aa", "bb","cc"), 15, replace=TRUE),
                 col3=sample(c('a','b','c','d'), 15, replace=TRUE,
                              prob=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.20, 0.30)))


grp<-df %>%
  group_by(col2, col3) %>%
  summarise(n=n(), rows=paste(col1, collapse = ", "))
grp

col2   col3     n               rows
(fctr) (fctr) (int)              (chr)
aa      b     6 5, 1, 15, 13, 8, 3
aa      c     1                  9
bb      a     3           6, 12, 4
bb      b     1                  2
bb      d     1                 11
cc      c     1                 14
cc      d     2              7, 10
```

If you need it to be separate (as in detached from df) then just `rowsByGrp<-grp$rows` and use that vector however you need. If you want it to actually be a named `list`, then:

```
rowsByGrp<-grp$rows 
rows.list<-lapply(1:length(rowsByGrp), function(x) rowsByGrp[x])
names(rows.list)<-paste(grp$col2 , grp$col3, sep = "_")
rows.list  

    $aa_b
[1] "5, 1, 15, 13, 8, 3"

$aa_c
[1] "9"

$bb_a
[1] "6, 12, 4"

$bb_b
[1] "2"

$bb_d
[1] "11"

$cc_c
[1] "14"

$cc_d
[1] "7, 10"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bryan :)